# ElasticSearch/Neptune alternative solution for graph relations

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

So I have the following setup on AWS:

1. Upload file(s) into S3 bucket.
2. S3 bucket triggers AWS Lambda to index the file(s) into ElasticSearch.

Each file has a graph relation to other file. So one file upload in the S3 bucket will trigger multiple ES doc update.

So this setup is clumsy and too complicated, so I started looking at Neptune. However, the cost is too high for Neptune.

Any better solutions out there? A better way to store tree-structure inside ES?

Comment: Which certification(s) do you need?